# is it possible to replace the Phone App or the Lockscreen?

Tags: android, system

just a stupid question.
Is it possible to write an app that replaces the standard functions of Android like the Phone App or the lockscreen. I've never saw any kind of this Apps. Is there a restriction of Google?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to write an app that replaces the standard functions of Android like the... lockscreen.

Not as an SDK application. A lockscreen can only be replaced by creating your own firmware.

Answer (score 0):

No restriction from Google.
Actually, some VOIP dialers are there to replace the phone application.

There are not much examples, because, there is not much scope of development in the apps you mentioned.
For example, why would someone install a new app when he can make calls and do everything related to phone calls using the existing app?
Professional developers first estimate number of prospective users before developing.

Comment: I think the Lockscreen looks so ugly an there are so many other ways to unlock the phone :D But no idea is implemented